# Canvas is not drawing image in code, but does in developer console

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create class which will draw map and characters in canvas. When I'm refreshing canvas in my code nothing appears. But when I write map.refresh() in Chrome's developer console it just appears.
Here's my TypeScript code:

```
class Map {
    width:number = 800;
    height:number = 600;
    img:HTMLImageElement;
    objectList = [];

    constructor(img:string) {

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if(!ctx) {
            console.log("Canvas error");
        }

        this.loadMap(img);

    }
    refresh() : any {
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        for(var i = 0; i < this.objectList.length; i++) {
            var obj = this.objectList[i];
            ctx.drawImage(obj.img, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    loadMap(img:string) {
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = img;
        this.img.onload = <any> this.registerObject(this);
    }

    registerObject(obj:Object) {
        this.objectList.push(obj);
        this.refresh();
    }

}
```

And my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="map.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
            var map = new Map("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Worldmap_LandAndPolitical.jpg/1200px-Worldmap_LandAndPolitical.jpg");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
this.img.onload = <any> this.registerObject(this);
                                           ^^^^^^ (invokes function)
```

will pass `undefined` to `onload` as the function is first called, then the result of the function (`undefined`) is passed. The callback should be referenced instead.

You can change the argument to `onload` to take a function definition, bind `this` to it (otherwise `this` will represent the image itself) and call `this.registerObject(this.img)` from inside it.